# Pass argument as default argument to all unnamed function arguments

Tags: r, function

What is a nice way to pass a default argument to all the unspecified arguments of a function?  For example, using `list.dirs` there are three arguments: `path`, `full.names`, and `recursive`.  In this example. I would like to supply the path argument and then a default argument (FALSE) that gets passed to all the remaining function arguments.  In this example it is obviously no problem to simply specify `FALSE` to the two remaining arguments, but what if there were a lot of arguments that I wanted to specify with the default?

Something equivalent to

```
list.dirs(path=".", full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE)
```

but with something like (which doesn't work)

```
do.call("list.dirs", list(path=".", FALSE))
```

or (also doesn't work)

```
do.call("list.dirs", list(path=".", rep(FALSE, 2)))
```

Comment: I think you just make your list incorrectly. Try `do.call("list.dirs", c(list(path="."), as.list(rep(FALSE, 2))))`

Comment: Did you want to set all arguments to the same value (e.g. FALSE)? That seems like a rare case, but you can get a list of arguments using `formals()`, and replicate `FALSE` according to the length of that list (perhaps minus the number of arguments you set yourself).    `do.call("list.dirs", c(list("."), replicate(length(formals("list.dirs"))-1,expr = "FALSE")))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `formals()` to return a list of arguments, length() to get the number of arguments, and replicate to create a list of 'default' arguments the right length (minus the arguments set manually).

```
do.call("list.dirs", c(list("."), replicate(length(formals("list.dirs"))-1,expr = "FALSE")))
```